# Return last amount for each element with same ref_id

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have 2 tables, one is credit and other one is creditdetails.
Creditdetails creates new row every day for each of credit.

```
ID  Amount  ref_id    date
 1     2       1      16.03
 2     3       1      17.03 
 3     4       1      18.03
 4     1       2      16.03
 5     2       2      17.03
 6     0       2      18.03
```

I want to sum up amount of every row with the unique id and last date. So the output should be 4 + 0.

Comment: If you have two tables, why are you only showing one?

Comment: First table is just ID and data.

Comment: What did you try? Variants of this type of question has been asked and answered. Search the `greatest-n-per-group` tag.

Comment: SUM(amount) (grouped by ref_id) would be 9 and 3, please be more specific.

Comment: I dont need to group, I want to take last amount for every ref_id, for id 1 it would be 4 and for id 2 it would be 0. And then I sum them.

Comment: Is id an auto increment column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ROW_NUMBER to filter on the latest amount per ref_id.

Then SUM it.

```
SELECT SUM(q.Amount) AS TotalLatestAmount
FROM
(
  SELECT 
   cd.ref_id,
   cd.Amount,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cd.ref_id ORDER BY cd.date DESC) AS rn
  FROM Creditdetails cd
) q
WHERE q.rn = 1;
```

A test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=e875b1c665cd2497b1fb3438a6e7b69a)*

Answer (score 1):

With this query:

```
select ref_id, max(date) maxdate 
from creditdetails
group by ref_id
```

you get all the last `date`s for each `ref_id`, 
so you can `join` it to the table `creditdetails` and sum over `amount`:

```
select sum(amount) total 
from creditdetails c inner join (
  select ref_id, max(date) maxdate 
  from creditdetails
  group by ref_id
) g
on g.ref_id = c.ref_id and g.maxdate = c.date
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this,

```
select sum(amount) 
 from table
where date = ( select max(date) from table);
```

with the understanding that your *date* column doesn't appear to be in a standard format so I can't tell if it needs to be formatted in the query to work properly.